# Tkinter focar uma janela ignorando a de trás?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

No meu código tem um frame com um botão e que se chama "Abrir", ao clicar em "Abrir" ira aparecer outra janela.

O problema e que, se eu clicar na janela que esta o botão "Abrir" novamente, ele ira abrir uma nova janela.

O que quero é poder alternar entre todas as janelas abertas, selecionando qualquer uma. Quando eu clicar novamente no botão abrir da janela ela não deve abrir o botão novamente e sim alternar para a janela.

não sei se tem como fazer isso, vi algumas coisas sobre *grab* mas não entendi muito se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço desde já!

```
#-*- coding:UTF-8 -*-
from Tkinter import *

class novo:

    def __init__(self, janela):

        self.caixa=Frame(janela)
        self.caixa.grid()
        self.b=Button(janela, text='Abrir', command=self.new_jan)
        self.b.grid()
        self.l1=Label(janela, text='raiz!')
        self.l1.grid()

    def new_jan(self):
        jan=Tk()
        self.l=Label(jan, text='apenas fechando essa janela poderá voltar ou clicar na raiz!')
        self.l.grid()
        jan.geometry('300x200')

root=Tk()

novo(root)
root.geometry('300x200')

root.mainloop()
novo()
```

Comment: Seria bom se você pudesse acrescentar a sua perguntas, o código que você já possui e indicar através dele qual a sua duvida, fica mais fácil para que as pessoas possam te ajudar, além de aumentar o interesse delas na sua pergunta

Comment: Prontinho agora acho que vai para entender!

Comment: fiz uma edição na sua pergunta, confere se é exatamente isso oque você está perguntando, pois como você não colocou pontos ou quebras de linha ficava difícil de entender

Comment: Vejamos como posso te explicar melhor, pense no seguinte tem um frame chamado frame1, e um botão que abre outro frame que e chamado frame2, ao aparecer o frame2 quero que ocorra o seguinte, não poder selecionar o frame1 de forma alguma ate que o frame2 tenha sido fechado, acho que e algo como wait_window! qualquer coisa tenho Skype e posso te mostrar oque eu realmente quero por meio do remote.
PS: Vlw mesmo cara por se esforçar em poder me ajudar!

Comment: sugiro que adicione essa explicação a sua pergunta, edite ela da forma que deixe clara, como você deixou com esse comentario... fica mais facil ara quem souber como ajudar

Comment: blz mas consegui resolver o meu problema aqui andei dando uma estudada e consegui resolver usando Toplevel e transient!

Comment: então assim que você puder, coloque sua resposta, explicando como resolveu, a duvida de um pode ser a duvida de outros

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sua proposta original era simplesmente trazer a janela para frente quando ela já tivesse sido aberta. Isso é realizado pelo seguinte código:

```py
#-*- coding:UTF-8 -*-
from Tkinter import *

class novo:

    def __init__(self, janela):
        # Inicia como None
        self.jan = None
        self.caixa=Frame(janela)
        self.caixa.grid()
        self.b=Button(janela, text='Abrir', command=self.new_jan)
        self.b.grid()
        self.l1=Label(janela, text='raiz!')
        self.l1.grid()

    def new_jan(self):
        # Verifica se já foi criada
        if self.jan is None:
            self.jan=Tk()
            self.jan.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.fecha_jan)
            self.l=Label(self.jan, text='apenas fechando essa janela poderá voltar ou clicar na raiz!')
            self.l.grid()
            self.jan.geometry('300x200')
        else:
            # Se já foi, basta colocá-la na frente
            self.jan.lift()

    def fecha_jan(self):
        # Seta de novo em None para recriar quando abrir
        self.jan.destroy()
        self.jan = None

root=Tk()

novo(root)
root.geometry('300x200')

root.mainloop()
novo()
```

Comment: Muito obrigado por sua ajuda meu caro, não sabia o que fazer realmente quebrei a cabeça para entender e você me mostra de uma forma clara e simples de se fazer isso, tenha um ótimo dia!

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver o meu problema da seguinte forma...
note que ao abrir a janela clicando em abrir a janela aberta se torna o foco e não tem como mexer na de traz em quanto não fechar ela!

```
#-*- coding:UTF-8 -*-
from Tkinter import *
root=Tk()

class novo:

        def __init__(self, janela):
            self.caixa=Frame(janela)
            self.caixa.grid()
            self.b=Button(janela, text='Abrir', command=self.new_jan)
            self.b.grid()
            self.l1=Label(janela, text='raiz!')
            self.l1.grid()

        def new_jan(self):
            self.jan=Toplevel()
            self.l=Label(self.jan, text='Feche esta para poder voltar a raiz!')
            self.l.grid()
            b=Button(self.jan, text='Fechar', command=self.fecha_jan)
            b.grid()
            self.jan.geometry('300x200')
            self.jan.transient(root)#
            self.jan.focus_force()#
            self.jan.grab_set()#

        def fecha_jan(self):
            self.jan.destroy()


novo(root)

root.geometry('300x200')

root.mainloop()
```